# Переменные и база данных с локализацией

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Я новичок. Есть следующий код:

```
 @{
    int i = 0;
    string ii = ".png";
}

@{
    int Achievement1 = 3;
    int Achievement2 = 300;
    int Achievement3 = 500000;

    int[] array = new int[]
        {
           Achievement1,
           Achievement2,
           Achievement3,
        };
}

@foreach (Web.Models.DataBase.Achievements info in ViewBag.info)
{
    @foreach (var ach in array)
    {
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="well well-sm">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 text-center">
                        <img src="~/images/achievements/Achievement@{}@i@ii" alt="Achievement"
                             class="img-rounded img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-9 section-box">
                        <span class="achievement-title-size">
                            @Localizer["Achievement.Title"]
                            @if (@info.Achievement1 >= @ach / 3)
                            {
                                <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star text-warning"></span>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty text-warning"></span>
                            }
                            @if (@info.Achievement1 >= @ach / 3 * 2)
                            {
                                <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star text-warning"></span>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty text-warning"></span>
                            }
                            @if (@info.Achievement1 >= @ach)
                            {
                                <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star text-warning"></span>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty text-warning"></span>
                            }
                        </span>
                        <p class="achievement-text-size">
                            @Localizer["Achievement.Info1"]
                        </p>
                        @if (@info.@Achievement1 >= ach)
                        {
                            <dt class="text-warning">Достижение выполнено</dt>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <span class="pull-right achievement-text-size">
                                @info.Achievement1<span>/</span>@ach
                            </span>
                            <div class="row rating-desc">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="achievement-progress">
                                        <progress max="@ach" value="@info.Achievement1">
                                        </progress>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

В нём как и требуется я могу перебрать несколько изображений и переменных с некоторыми значениями создав в представлении всего 1 блок с дизайном. а как в моём случае быть с **@info.Achievement1**, который уже берётся не с переменной а с модели базы данных и **@Localizer["Achievement.Info1"]**? Мне необходимо как то подставлять так же 1,2,3 и так далее. Спасибо за любой совет!

Comment: `@Localizer["Achievement.Info" + i]`

Comment: Но напрашивается либо коллекция вместо кучи свойств, либо нормальное (описательное) название для каждого свойства.

Comment: Здравствуйте. @Localizer["Achievement.Info" + i] мне всегда прибавляет 0. А мне нужно прибавлять единичку, тем самым из файла ресурсов тянуть нужную строку. "(описательное) название для каждого свойства" Можно подробнее?

Comment: Добрый день. Сделайте так, чтобы в `i` циферки менялись. Например - цикл от 1 до количества этих ваших свойств.

Comment: Если значение вам известно на этапе компиляции - это можно отражать в названии. Например `BestGoogleUserAchievement`.

Comment: Да, вроде сработало. Спасибо большое.